# Can Java's Threadlocal be applied to a non-static field, if yes, how?

Tags: java, multithreading

ThreadLocal ensures a field is global and local to a thread. (Global because it is available to all methods in the thread and local because it is confined to that thread's stack alone.)

This made little sense to me as each thread's stack is confined to that thread alone. So it is already 'threadlocal', right ?

Why then do we need ThreadLocal ? - On further reading, I confirmed my assumption from various sites (a majority of which fail to provide these facts or contradict each other) that this is indeed applicable for **static fields**. 
Which does make sense.

So my question is, is there ever a multi-threading scenario where ThreadLocal can/needs to be applied to non-static fields ? (I came across some sites that say 'ThreadLocal' is "*mainly*" used for static fields; even https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html uses the word "*typically*")

Comment: Yes, ThreadLocals work in instances as well. However the "advantage" of a thread local is, that you have easy access to it. When you do not put it into a static field you lose that advantage as you have to hand around the actual holder instance. It helps to think of a ThreadLocal as a HashMap where Thread.currentThread() is the key.

Comment: I think the "global" term is just plain wrong. Don't bother with it. There are enough samples where you explicitely do not want to have the thread (write) access to it, for example security or transaction context. This is typically done with a package or private visible field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only local variables are on a thread's stack.* Static variables and instance variables both live on the heap. If we wanted to, we could also just pass a `ThreadLocal` around by itself without it ever living inside an object or class.

We could view `ThreadLocal` as a *local variable* which could be accessible at *any point in time*.

Normal local variables are destroyed when the scope they are declared in returns, but a `ThreadLocal` can live anywhere.

> So my question is, is there ever a multi-threading scenario where ThreadLocal can/needs to be applied to non-static fields?

We can make one up...

```
interface Dial {}

class Gadget {
    ThreadLocal<Dial> d = new ThreadLocal<>();
}

class Gizmo implements Runnable {
    Gadget g;
    Gizmo(Gadget g) {
        this.g = g;
    }
    public void run() {}
}

{
    Gadget g = new Gadget();
    new Thread(new Gizmo(g)).start();
    new Thread(new Gizmo(g)).start();
}
```

Both threads share the same instance of `Gadget` but has their own local `Dial`.

> Why then do we need ThreadLocal?

The truth is we don't need `ThreadLocal` very often, if at all.

---

* Only local variables are on a thread's stack except in the case of a theoretical optimization [the JVM is allowed to do](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp09275/index.html) where objects can be stack allocated. We would never find out about this if it happened because it would not be allowed to change the behavior of the program. If an object is shared between threads, it's on the heap.

Comment: Thanks for the clear-cut explanation. Let's see if I understand this right - so the main reason for the leak to happen is that, a ThreadLocal which is not destroyed, sits on the heap, (and so is governed by the GC) - How is this different from other objects ?

Comment: I wasn't aware leaks were part of your question so my answer doesn't address that. Memory leaks with ThreadLocal depend on the application keeping references to threads which aren't being used, such as from e.g. a thread pool. Keeping a reference to a Thread is what causes a leak, not keeping a reference to a ThreadLocal.

Comment: Sorry should have been clearer - I got the concept of TLs resulting in memory leaks if they are not destroyed  from the other answers. I just thought I would comment on your answer as you had mentioned the TLs will sit on the heap, but again, you have answered that too, so I will mark this as accepted. Thanks !

Answer (score 7):

I think that this Question is based on a false premise.

> ThreadLocal ensures a field is global and local to a thread. (Global because it is available to all methods in the thread and local because it is confined to that thread's stack alone.)

This is not what "global" really means.  Global really means accessible to the entire program without any qualification.  And in fact, Java doesn't have true global variables.  The closest it has is "public static" fields ... which are accessible with qualification.

But back to the Question ...

A threadlocal *variable* is available to a method if two conditions are satisfied:

- The method *call* must be on the correct thread.  (If it is on a different thread, it sees a different variable.)
- The method must be able to get hold of the `ThreadLocal` object that effectively "declares" the thread local variable (in any thread).

Does the 2nd condition imply that the "declaration" is global?

IMO, no.  For two reasons.

- Global variables in the conventional sense have only one instance.  A thread local has a distinct instance for each thread.
- The fact that the `ThreadLocal` is accessible to a specific method does not make it accessible to any method.  The normal (and good practice) usage pattern for a `ThreadLocal` is to hold the object reference in a `private static` variable.  That means that methods *in the same class* can use the corresponding thread local variable instances ... but methods in other classes can't.

Now it is possible to put the reference to `ThreadLocal` in a `public static` variable, but why would you do that?  You are explicitly creating a *leaky abstraction* ... which is liable to cause problems.

And of course, you can do what @Radiodef's answer shows; i.e. create a thread local whose instances are only accessible from methods on a specific instance of a specific class.  But it is hard to understand why you would want / need to go to that level of confinement.  (And it is liable to lead to storage leaks ...)

---

Short answer:  if you don't want your thread local variables to be accessible, restrict access to the `ThreadLocal` object.

Answer (score 4):

```
static ThreadLocal<Whatever> threadLocal;
```

Declares a field that points to an instance of class `ThreadLocal`. Each Thread has a `Map<ThreadLocal<?>, Object>` that associates instances of `ThreadLocal` with the value the corresponding "thread local variable" has for this `Thread`. That is, each `ThreadLocal` instance *identifies* a "thread local variable", and as far as the JVM is concerned, `ThreadLocal` is a class like any other.

Usually, when we need a "thread local variable", we only need a single one, and therefore create only a single `ThreadLocal` instance, which is often kept in a static field for convenient access.

If we need a new "thread local variable" for every instance of the host object, we could simply create a new ThreadLocal instance for every host object, and store in an a non-static field. Off hand, I can't think of a case where this is the simplest solution, but we could do it.

Comment: I did a significant amount of work recently with Java ee6.  During that time I came to the opinion that in most cases an injected singleton scoped object is much better in most cases than a static reference and provides the same level of access to the services. This type of access to a common variable is a case where a nonstatic thread local provides a great solution.

Answer (score 2):

Threadlocal is a container for a set of variables each one of which is only available to one thread, ie it provides an instance of the contained class for each thread. So the ThreadLocal object is globally available (spending on permissions) but each instance of the contained class is only locally available to the thread.

This means that it needs to be initialized and destroyed for each thread   slightly differently but in all other ways it is the same as any other variable.

Note : The point of destroying instances is to prevent memory leaks or leakage of state between independent invocations on the same thread if threads are being drawn from a pool.

Thread local variables are often used to provide a thread safe option for storage where there is no need for communication between threads. One such example is to define a new scope in CDI where that scope will exist wholly within a single thread (eg you could define an asynchronous request scope).

As such there is no need to restrict it to static or non-static variables as long as it is accessible where it is needed. In a default java environment Static variables are a convenient way of providing such access but in CDI a Singleton bean can provide the same level of access with many advantages.

In the injected singleton case the singleton bean would contain a nonstatic reference to the ThreadLocal and provide services to access the instances contained therein. Both the references to the injected singleton and the singleton's reference to the ThreadLocal would be non static.

Comment: Thread locals dont have anything to do with "instance of contained class" (whatever that is :). And not even public statics are global in Java, so how could a ThreadLocal be...

Comment: ThreadLocal is a container for a set of objects, each one of which is only available to one thread. What I mean by contained class is the class that is  instantiated by the objects in that set.Why is everyone so hung up about the difference between the theory of global variables and static variables. The question was can threadlocal be non static. I have edited my answer to clarify this (I hope)

Comment: I was puzzled by that too, the question wasn't about scope but why only statics seem to be commonly used with TLs.